# Unity Tweak Tool for Precise?

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-tweak-tool

I've been looking everywhere for Unity Tweak Tool in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise but I can't seem to find it so could anyone help?

Answer (score 12):

Unity Tweak Tool (*unity-tweak-tool*) can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 13.04 and later, but it is not available in the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 12.04. The application that is most similar to Unity Tweak Tool in the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 12.04 is MyUnity.

MyUnity allows one to configure and tune Unity with a pleasant and comfortable graphical interface. MyUnity is a third-party application, not an official part of the Unity project.

```
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

The GUI looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of MyUnity]

Comment: @user12.04ubuntu the way to say thanks is marking the answer as awnswered.