# How to use a theme.

Tags: themes

When I downloaded a theme, .tar.gz or .gz or some kind of format like that.  When I opened it, it was just a folder full of files.  How do I make it a theme or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some theme authors include an install script in the archive; if you find a file called INSTALL or something similar, extract the archive to a folder that is preferably easy to get to. Then open the terminal and cd to the applicable folder (probably `~/Downloads` by default). Then in terminal, run `./[Name-of-Install-Script]` to install.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to open your archive manager as root. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu [packagemanager]` where [packagemanager] is the command for the archive manager. (In not too heavily changed Ubuntu installations, this is `file-roller`.) Open the file, then extract the entire package to the directory `/usr/share/themes` (or `/usr/share/icons` for cursor themes or icon themes).

Next, you will need a program to apply the theme. I suggest the GNOME Tweak Tool. Install this by opening the terminal and typing these commands, one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Once this is done, you can either search for the tool in the HUD or run it directly by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> again and typing `gnome-tweak-tool`. In the dialog that appears, there should be some options on the left for "Theme". Click that, and change the theme settings to your liking. The effect should be immediate.

Comment: You can extract the contents to ~/.themes (or ~/.icons) if you want changes to be available to only the current user.

Answer (score 1):

The [Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEyeCandy) recommends that you extract the archives into either `~/usr/share/themes` or icons to `~/usr/share/icons`.

The recommended application to manage themes, `unity-tweak-tool`, is available from the **Ubuntu Software Center**.

From terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Alternatively, you can visit the project page http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ and download the debian file package. *Ubuntu-tweak* offers more configuration options than just customizing unity themes.

---

I had previously copied the recommendation for  the *Myunity* tool from the Community Pages, but it is no longer receiving popular attention.  The only thing close to an explanation that I could find [in the forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946425). Searching this site, it seems that [MyUnity is 3rd party software and is the solution for Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/355597/89515), but that the unity-tweak-tool is preferred for newer releases (my inference).

Additional edits incorporate advice from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/213702/89515).